# Error KAZE with opencv: Use of undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, feature-extraction, opencv-features2d

I tried to compile a function for extracting the features.
`Ptr<Feature2d> kaze = KAZE::create();`
But I get an errors with that. First is "Use of undeclared identifier 'KAZE'"
The next line is `kaze->detectAndCompute(img, noArray(), keypoints, descriptors);`. There it is said: "No member named 'detectAndCompute' in 'cv::Feature2D'".
I have included the header`#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>`and I also linked the libs. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Should this be `AKAZE`? http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/features2d/akaze_matching/akaze_matching.html

Comment: I have tried that too, but I get the same error :/ But thank you!

Comment: what version openCV are you using? in 2.4 this was a functor but changed into a proper method on opencv 3.0